# Add Numbers Until Value Reached

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I want to have a threshold value in one cell(A1) and take it as a reference for adding cells.

Suppose I have

A1 - **10**
A2 - 4
A3 - 2
A4 - 3
A5 - 4
A6 - 6

I want to add cells based on A1(Threshold). 
As A1 is 10, cells from A6:A5 should be added - Result:10
If A1 is 6 then cell A6 should be returned- Result:6
If A1 is 16 then cells from A6:A3 should be added - Result:19

Is this possible without VBA? Can i get count of number of cells in return along with sum?

Comment: if A1 = 6 then SUM(A6:A6) doesn't equal 6 (your statement). Your question needs clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added some progression `SUM` operation with `ROW` and `OFFSET` for the following. Note that I have modified and added to your sample data for more thorough results.

[image]

The `SUM` formula in C2 is `=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2, 0,0,ROW(1:99),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:99),,))+1,1))` anf the `COUNT` is derived in D2 with `=MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$2, 0,0,ROW(1:99),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:99),,))+1`. TBH, I didn't experiment much with zeroes in the data as I was unsure whether you would want to count them in the progression or not.

Comment: Before you ask, it may be possible to do this in reverse order but I feel that is something you can discover for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INDIRECT()` function.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A6:A"&ROUNDDOWN(A1/2,0)))
```

for the count use

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("A6:A"&ROUNDDOWN(A1/2,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it also possible to do it in reverse order? Its my bad to edit the question now. Sorry @CallumDS33

Comment: what do you mean by reverse order?

Comment: instead of summing from A2:A6, it should check from A6:A2.

and moreover, the above formula is not working if a1 value is 12 and 15

Comment: The ranges A2:A6 and A6:A2 are treated as the same thing in Excel, what error are you getting, I can't replicate the error. Also where did you put the formula? Don't put it into column A

Comment: No, I mean, First it should check from A6, if threshold is not met, then add a5 and so on till a2. I used this formula in column B. It may extend from A2:A32.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What is the "threshold" you are asking about? Consider editing your question to be more clear of **exactly** what you need

Comment: I mean the value of cell A1 is threshold.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to hit a moving target but for your revised parameters try the following.

`=SUM(OFFSET($A$6,0-MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$6,1-ROW(1:5),0,ROW(1:5),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:5),,)),0,MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$6,1-ROW(1:5),0,ROW(1:5),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:5),,))+1,1))`

`=MAX(INDEX((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$6,1-ROW(1:5),0,ROW(1:5),1))<$A$1)*ROW(1:5),,))+1`

While Excel expects to calculate in a *'down-and-to-the-right'* progression, the `OFFSET()` function will accept parameters to both relocate the starting point and reshape the height and width of the range of cells being summed. Generally, working *'down-and-to-the-right'* will allow to leave some breathing room for expansion but you will have to be very careful that you do not attempt to move upwards past row 1 (`#REF!` error).

[OFFSET function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/offset-function-HP010342739.aspx)

The formula could be simplified if there was any guarantee that nothing of numerical value was ever going to be below A6 but that point has not been addressed so my formulas halt the sum operation at A6.