# How many X cells to add to reach Y%

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, sum, rounding

I'm working on this: https://tempfile.me/download/nYhdQHD65GxRzk/ .

And I need to count how many `1` cells should be added to column A to reach a percentage of `1`s = 85%.

This is just an example, I can't add cells with `1` and see how many of them I need since it should be automated on a big sample of data.

Comment: try this maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274633/add-numbers-until-value-reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressed as:

```
.85(count + x) = sum + x
```

this renders down to x = ( (85 x count) - (100 x sum) ) / (100 - 85) or,

```
=(85*COUNT(A:A)-100*SUM(A:A))/(100-85)
```

However, this does not result in an integer, so to ensure 85% is reached:

```
=ROUNDUP((85*COUNT(A:A)-100*SUM(A:A))/(100-85),0)
```

The result (234) when added as `1`s increases the TRUE total to 284 and the count of all entries to 334, where 284/334 is 85.03%.

Comment: Beat me to it by a few minutes :D

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier, if you don't look at the percentage which is `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but at the count of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
In your example, you have 50 1's and 50 0's.
You want to see how many 1's you have to add in order to get a percentage of 1's of 85%.
In numbers this would look like this:

```
(x+dx)/(x+dx+y) = 0.85
```

where x is the number of 1's, y the number of 0's and dx the increase of 1's needed, to get to 85%.

You are looking for `dx`. So just solve for `dx` and you get:

```
dx = (0.85*y-0.15*x)/0.15
```

Which yields in your example an `dx = 234`. So you need to add another 234 1's in order to get a (minimum) 85% of 1's.

Hope this is what you wanted. It has however nothing to do with excel.